# Delphi 7 ADO, DBGrid combobox field

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

I have these tables in my MySQL database:

[image]

I want to display the employee table and job.jobName in DBGrid and allow user to edit it (using DBNavigator maybe).

So I created an ADOQuery with SELECT ... JOIN query, a DataSource and linked a DBGrid DataSource to it.
 [image]

Everything works, but instead of jobId field I want Job field which displays JobNames, allows to choose it via combobox and sets id in the employee.JobId.
Something like this:
[image]

I thought that I can achieve it using LookupKeyFields/LookupResultFields properties for JobId field in ADOQuery but in fact it doesn't work for me.

I added an ADOTable which just loads everything from the job table and set JobId field (in ADOQuery) properties: FieldKind = **fkLookup**, KeyFields = **JobId**, LookupDataSet = **tblJob**, LookupKeyFields = **IdJob**, LookupResultFields = **JobName**.

[image]

But now Job column is just empty and without comboboxes.

Also I found PickList property in DBGrid columns, but it is TStrings, so it allows only displayed string, not separate displayed strings and values. And it did nothing even when I tried to fill it for string field (LastName).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your qryEmployes dataset, choose `new field` ans assign needed values.

[image: Sorry for german version]